# Is there a simpler way to get formData with pure js?

Tags: javascript, form-data

My html structure is as below,a table nested in form, some info in `input` or `option` in `select` will send via ajax.

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>date</td>
        <td><input class="data" type='text' name="date"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>
        <select id="type" name="type">
            <option value="word">word</option>
            <option value="phase">phrase</option>
            <option value="sentence">sentence</option>
            <option value="grammar">grammar</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td><textarea  class="data" name='content' cols="80" rows="8"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>meaning</td>
        <td><textarea  class="data" name='meaning' cols="80" rows="8"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>source</td>
        <td><input class="data" type="text" name="source"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="submit" id="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I get the formData with below code, it is verified that all data in the form can get.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
var formData = new FormData(); 

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    formData.append(elements[i].name, elements[i].value);
}

var mySelect = document.getElementById("type");
var index = mySelect.selectedIndex;
var svalue = mySelect.options[index].value;
var sname = "type";
formDate.append(sname,svalue);
```

It is a bit long lines here, i want more small js code.
Is ther more simple way to get formData with pure js ,instead of jQuery?

Comment: "instead of jQuery" - but you're not using jquery here. With jquery it's indeed trivial, `$('#form').serialize()`

Comment: I mean that some post code which can not contain any jQuery.

Comment: If you just want to create a FormData object containing all parameters of the whole form, then you can simply pass the form element itself to the constructor. If you need to select only specific elements of the form, by class or some other criterion, then you will have to select those elements and add them one by one in a loop.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: We've had CSS for over two decades. It is time to stop using tables for layout.

Comment: @Quentin In this case, OP is populating tabular data and is perfectly fine.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar — The data appears to be a set of label/input pairs. That isn't tabular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for all input Element and Select element. if you have multiple forms, get form by Id. Thanks. If any errors let me know. typing from mobile.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

var formData = new FormData(); 
var ipts = elements.querySelector('input, select');
for(var ipt of ipts)
{
    formData.append( ipt.name, ipt.value );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just pass the whole form to the object.

```
var formData = new FormData( document.querySelector("form") )
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will return object with all keys and values that we have in the form

```
var formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.querySelector('form')).entries());
```

*result:*

```
{ key_1: value_1, key_2: value_2, key_3: value_3, ... }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.